# Css and Javascript is not parsed in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, iframe

In my node.js application I have set up an endpoint to where I load some parsed html code. Like this.

```
app.get('/code', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.send(code.html); 
});
```

code is an json object which looks like this.

```
code = { html: 'Bunch of html code i took from some site. This contains css and javascript code as well.' };
```

In my index file I have an iframe which looks like this.

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:port/code" width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

The iframe is working, but when I am trying to load the view most of the css and javascript is not parsed. I am getting the following error:

`Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

The html is being parsed, but the view looks a bit distorted and none of the css or javascript is being run correctly. If I open the network tab in chrome the request url looks like this.

`Request URL: http://localhost:3000/docs/4.3/assets/js/docs.min.js`

Every stylesheet and js code is being appended to my localhost url. Thats why the css and js is not being parsed right? How do I solve this?

Comment: If you're  sending a json, then your content-Type must be a json as well, res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: If I send json the html will not be parsed at all. The iframe just displays the entire html code. As you can see I am send code.html to the browser, not the entire object.

Comment: But you can convert it, can't you?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I am sending pure html, css and javascript code to the browser and setting the content type to text/html. I dont have to parse the json object, if that is what you mean.

Comment: But the error message is not about the JSON, it's about the Bootstrap CSS file. Are you sure the CSS files is there? Maybe the frame gets a 404 page instead.

Comment: can you show how does your `code.html` string looks like. also. how you are setting static resources path in express.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it but everything worked fine for me.
This is my code.

```
app.get('/code', (req, res) => {
  const code = {
    html: '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>
      <h1 class="button">Test</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
',
  };
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.send(code.html);
});
```

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:3121/code" width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yedl.png)